# Log in problem on MO

Tags: support, login

I am unable to log in, unfortunately. After I click log in on top there appears a bubble on top of the page saying "Welcome back Frode Bjørdal, You are logged in, You are being redirected", and then I am taken back to the previous page where the log in is there still to be clicked on. So I am caught in a vicious circle, one might say.

Comment: This might be silly but I don't get it: If you are not logged in, how have you been able to post this question as yourself?

Comment: Are you trying to log in to a different Stack Exchange site?  If you belong to one Stack Exchange site (like Mathoverflow) your name appears at the top bar if you visit it.  But if you go to a Stack Exchange site where you are not a user, then your name will not appear at the top bar.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Jonas Limavarta MO meta functions, obviosly, and MO does not.

Comment: @ Joel Reyes Noche I do not quite understand your question. I mean what I say. I asked Stack exchange meta to merge two accounts on MO, and it was done. My philosophy and physics accounts work after that attendment, and my TEX/Latex and MO accounts I am no longer able to log in to.

Comment: What happens when I click on login is that a bubble on top of the page appears and says untruthfully, as it turns out, "Welcome back Frode Bjørdal you are logged in / You are being redirected". I am then taken back to the page where I clicked log in at the top.

Comment: @ Joel Reyes Noche I now see that I stated my problem badly, so I attempted to be more exact now. Sorry, and thank you.

Comment: The problem now disappeared when switching from Mozilla Firefox to Google. I leave it to others to ponder why if it should be informative.

Comment: Did you try to clear cookies/cache of the browser where it did not work? For some reason something might haven been left in a corrupted stated.